# My \Render that attempts to iterate a list and invoke macros dynamically produces errors

Tags: programming

My `\Render` that attempts to iterate a list and invoke macros dynamically produces errors. The given MWE with detailed comments tells what my objective is. How to fix it? I have no more idea how to fix the following errors:

> [image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{filecontents}
% There is a huge number of Japanese words as follows.
% Format: \NewWord{<word macro name>}{<word in Kanji>}{<meaning in English>}
\begin{filecontents*}{vocabularies.tex}
\NewWord{watashi}{私}{I}
\NewWord{ki@spirit}{気}{spirit}
\NewWord{ki@tree}{木}{tree}
\NewWord{aikidou}{合気道}{aikidou}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf}
\usepackage{pgffor}

% \FlashCard is used to create a flash card.
% Format: \FlashCard{<word in Kanji>}{<meaning in English>}
\newcommand\FlashCard[2]{\fbox{#1: #2} }

\gdef\Pushed{}
% \Push is used to push "macro name" into \Pushed.
% \Pushed is a comma separated list of "macro name".
\newcommand\Push[1]{\xdef\Pushed{#1,\Pushed}}


% #1: macro name, 
% #2: word in Kanji, 
% #3: meaning in English
% ----------------------
\newcommand\NewWord[3]{%
    %
    % create conditional macro
    \expandafter\newif\csname if#1IsInserted\endcsname
    % set the conditional macro to false
    \csname #1IsInsertedfalse\endcsname
    %
    % create flash card macro   
    \expandafter\newrobustcmd\csname#1FlashCard\endcsname{\FlashCard{#2}{#3}}%
    %
    % create "word macro",
    \expandafter\newrobustcmd\csname#1\endcsname[1][#2]{%
        % output
        ##1%
        % uniqueness routine
        \csname if#1IsInserted\endcsname
        % do nothing
        \else
            \Push{#1} 
            \csname #1IsInsertedtrue\endcsname
        \fi
    }%
}


\newcommand\Render{%
    \par Flash Cards:\\[12pt]%
    % For each <element> in \Pushed, invoke its <element>FlashCard and
    % set <element>IsInserted to false.
    \foreach \x in \Pushed {\csname\x FlashCard\endcsname\global\csname\x IsInsertedfalse\endcsname}%
    %
    % Make \Pushed empty
    \gdef\Pushed{}%
}

\makeatletter
\input{vocabularies.tex}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\watashi は合\ki@spirit 道が好きです。 いい天\ki@spirit ですので、木の下に座っています。
\Render

\item 
\ki@tree の下に誰もいないです。
\Render
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the posted code runs without error in texlive 2015 xelatex. please don't just have a title "please fix this error" make title (and words in the question) describe the error so it is useful for future searching in the archive

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: See my last update. I think the code you tested is my first code where `\Render` was commented (disabled). Please kindly try the last one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a trailing `,` in your list and that meant in the last step `\x` was empty and generated errors:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{filecontents}
% There is a huge number of Japanese words as follows.
% Format: \NewWord{<word macro name>}{<word in Kanji>}{<meaning in English>}
\begin{filecontents*}{vocabularies.tex}
\NewWord{watashi}{私}{I}
\NewWord{ki@spirit}{気}{spirit}
\NewWord{ki@tree}{木}{tree}
\NewWord{aikidou}{合気道}{aikidou}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf}
\usepackage{pgffor}

% \FlashCard is used to create a flash card.
% Format: \FlashCard{<word in Kanji>}{<meaning in English>}
\newcommand\FlashCard[2]{\fbox{#1: #2} }

\gdef\Pushed{}
% \Push is used to push "macro name" into \Pushed.
% \Pushed is a comma separated list of "macro name".
\newcommand\Push[1]{\xdef\Pushed{#1\ifx\Pushed\empty\else,\Pushed\fi}}


% #1: macro name, 
% #2: word in Kanji, 
% #3: meaning in English
% ----------------------
\newcommand\NewWord[3]{%
    %
    % create conditional macro
    \expandafter\newif\csname if#1IsInserted\endcsname
    % set the conditional macro to false
    \csname #1IsInsertedfalse\endcsname
    %
    % create flash card macro   
    \expandafter\newrobustcmd\csname#1FlashCard\endcsname{\FlashCard{#2}{#3}}%
    %
    % create "word macro",
    \expandafter\newrobustcmd\csname#1\endcsname[1][#2]{%
        % output
        ##1%
        % uniqueness routine
        \csname if#1IsInserted\endcsname
        % do nothing
        \else
            \Push{#1} 
            \csname #1IsInsertedtrue\endcsname
        \fi
    }%
}


\newcommand\Render{%
    \par Flash Cards:\\[12pt]%
    % For each <element> in \Pushed, invoke its <element>FlashCard and
    % set <element>IsInserted to false.
%\show\Pushed
    \foreach \x in \Pushed {%
%\show\x
\csname\x FlashCard\endcsname\global\csname\x IsInsertedfalse\endcsname}%
    %
    % Make \Pushed empty
    \gdef\Pushed{}%
}

\makeatletter
\input{vocabularies.tex}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\watashi は合\ki@spirit 道が好きです。 いい天\ki@spirit ですので、木の下に座っています。
\Render

\item 
\ki@tree の下に誰もいないです。
\Render
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```